# Combining Pod AntiAffinity soft and hard preferences for scheduling pods

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to configure Pod Anti-Affinity rules for `Pod A` and `node X` in Kubernetes 1.24 EKS environment. The scheduling rules are as follows:

1. `Pod A` should prefer to schedule on a node without any other `Pod A`.
2. If all nodes already have `Pod A` running, a new `Pod A` can be assigned to a node with `Pod A` running.

I attempted to implement the following rule:

```yaml
podAntiAffinity:
  requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - labelSelector:
        matchExpressions:
          - key: app
            operator: In
            values:
              - web-store
       topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
  preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - podAffinityTerm:        
        labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: app 
            operator: In
            values:
              - web-store 
        topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      weight: 100
```

However, this led to scheduling two `Pod A` on the same node which goes against the first condition. How can I modify the rule to meet the specified scheduling conditions?

Answer (score 0):

After further research on this topic found below approaches to handle this use case -
Approach A -

1. Use only soft preferences rule as both hard and soft preference will not work for podAntiaffinity

   ```
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - podAffinityTerm:        
            labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
                - key: app 
                  operator: In
                  values:
                    - web-store 
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
          weight: 100
   ```

This rule will make best attempt to satisfy 1 but its not guaranteed always.
It will always satisfy 2.

Approach B -
This may vary for each environment but in general we need to check below

1. There could be other plug-in contributing to prefer the same node.
   For instance, NodeResourceFit might be configured with MostAllocated policy, in which the worker with more resources allocated (assigned) will be preferred over least allocated.
2. Check the scheduler logs for any hint on how scheduling is taking place in your environment.
3. Use Custom scheduler [could be last option]
4. Use kube scheduler simulator to understand the behaviour in your environment and then do advanced customisation.
   Help - GitHub.com/kubernetes-sigs/kube-scheduler-simulator